# How to print LaTex in Python 3 Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently in a python class, and we're learning about some of scipy's functions - my question is only vaguely related to that.  We were tasked with creating a .quad code to solve the integral:

[Definite Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU74a.jpg)

I came up with:

```
def int1(x):

return (x**2*math.exp(-x)*math.sin(x))

integral1 = quad(int1,0,10)

print('Int[0,10](x^2*e^(-x)*sin(x) dx) = {:}'.format(integral1[0]))
```

This solves the question, but I would like to present my answer in a more elegant form.  I'd love to have the integral print out in LaTex; I know in Markup mode, I can write this as:

```
$$ \int_{0}^{10}x^2e^{-x}\sin(x) \,dx $$
```

Is there any way to have the `print()` function output the integral in LaTex, followed by an = then the value?

I'm programming in Anaconda3 through a Jupyter Notebook on Windows.

Comment: You can make a Latex object using `IPython.display.Latex`, and display it with `IPython.display.display`.